# C# Winforms - Data Bindings with Same Property Name for Different Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am using data bindings in my Winforms application to connect the UI elements to an underlying object. My UI has several `ComboBoxes` in it, each pertaining to a different property of the class. Take the following simplified code, for example:

### Object which implements `INotifyPropertyChange`

```
class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChange
{
    // Custom logic in setters calls OnPropertyChanged
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

### Assigning the data source

```
BindingSource MyDataSource = new BindingSource(this.components);
MyDataSource.Add(instanceOfMyObject);
```

### Creating bindings

```
Binding binding1 = new Binding("SelectedIndex", MyDataSource, "Property1",
                                false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
binding1.Format += FormatForBinding1();
comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(binding1);

Binding binding2 = new Binding("SelectedIndex", MyDataSource, "Property2"
                                false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
binding2.Format += FormatForBinding2();
comboBox2.DataBindings.Add(binding2);
```

My issue is that when `comboBox2.SelectedIndex` changes, both `Format` handlers are called, which is not desired, when I only want `FormatForBinding2()` to be invoked. Is there a way to solve this? Am I misunderstanding something about bindings in that I cannot have multiple bindings with the same property name and the same data source, although the controls are different?

Comment: why is it a problem that both these methods are called? Does it do something undesirable? You didn't show us those methods so it's hard to know.

Comment: @ADyson Essentially one of the `Formats` changes the items in combo2, resulting in a fight to set the selected index of `comboBox2` when `Property2` is changed (bad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was with the code being executed in the `Format` handlers. The `Format` handler should only be used to do what it's name implies -- format the value. Adding extra logic can lead to undesirable behavior, as I found out. One thing to consider is, along with the `Format` handler, also including a `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectedValueChanged` handler for the desired ComboBox and doing the other logic in there.

Comment: Put all logic inside viewmodel (instanceOfMyObject) unless the logic is only view related.